# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when running Liquibase

Tags: sql, exception, liquibase

I am using Spring and Liquibase to deploy the following SQL code:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_clear_name_city(IN dirty TEXT, OUT clear TEXT) AS $$ SELECT trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(trim(dirty), '^(г |пгт |рп |кп |п |к |нп |п.ст |п ж/д ст |г. |пгт. |рп. |кп. |дп. |гп. |п. |к. |нп. |п.ст. |п. ж/д ст|п. ж/д ст.|п ж/д ст. |ж/д блокпост |ж/д будка |ж/д ветка |ж/д казарма |ж/д комбинат |ж/д платформа |ж/д площадка |ж/д путевой пост |ж/д остановочный пункт |ж/д рзд |ж/д ст |местечко |д |с |сл |ст |ст-ца |у |х |рзд |д. |с. |м |м. |сл. |ст. |у. |х. |рзд. |зимовье |город |гидрологический пост |поселок городского типа |рабочий поселок |рабочий посёлок |курортный поселок |дачный поселок |городской поселок |поселок |посёлок |кишлак |населенный пункт |поселок при станции (поселок станции) |поселок при железнодорожной станции |железнодорожный блокпост |железнодорожная будка |железнодорожная ветка |железнодорожная казарма |железнодорожный комбинат |железнодорожная платформа |железнодорожная площадка |железнодорожный путевой пост |железнодорожный остановочный пункт |железнодорожный разъезд |железнодорожная станция |местечко |межселенные территории |метеостанция |монтерский пункт |деревня |село |сельское поселение |городское поселение |слобода |станция |станица |улус |усадьба |хутор |разъезд |зимовье )?', '', 'i'), '( сельское поселение| городское поселение)$', '', 'i')); $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_clear_name_state(IN dirty TEXT, OUT clear TEXT) AS $$ SELECT trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(trim(dirty), '^(город |городской округ |г |г. |закрытое административно-территориальное образование город |муниципальное образование город |муниципальное образование |муниципальный район |муниципальный р-н |м.район |мун.район |м. район |мун. район |р |р. |р/н |р-н )?', '', 'i'), ' республики.*', '', 'i'), '( район| р| р.| р/н| р-н| сельское поселение| городское поселение| муниципальный район| м.район| мун.район| м. район| мун. район| город| городской округ| г| г.| закрытое административно-территориальное образование| муниципальное образование)$', '', 'i')); $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

DELETE FROM city;
DELETE FROM state;
CREATE TYPE oktmo_name AS (oktmo TEXT, name TEXT);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION city_set(parent_oktmo INTEGER)
  RETURNS SETOF oktmo_name AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
       'WITH RECURSIVE cities_oktmo AS (
         SELECT * FROM oktmo WHERE oktmo.parent_id = ' || parent_oktmo ||
         'UNION ALL
         SELECT oktmo.* FROM oktmo
           JOIN cities_oktmo ON oktmo.parent_id = cities_oktmo.id
       )
       SELECT city.oktmo::TEXT, city.name::TEXT FROM cities_oktmo city
       LEFT JOIN cities_oktmo child ON city.id = child.parent_id
       WHERE child.oktmo ISNULL AND char_length(city.oktmo) = 11
       ORDER BY city.name';
  END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DO $$
  DECLARE
    state_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT oktmo, name FROM oktmo
    WHERE parent_id = (select m.value::BIGINT from "public"."messages" m WHERE m.key='branding.region.oktmo');         state_guid UUID;
  BEGIN
    FOR st IN state_cursor LOOP
      state_guid := uuid_generate_v4();
      INSERT INTO state(guid, oktmo, name, clear_name) VALUES(state_guid, st.oktmo, st.name, get_clear_name_state(st.name));
      INSERT INTO city(oktmo, name, clear_name, state_guid)
      SELECT oktmo, name, get_clear_name_city(name), state_guid
      FROM city_set(st.oktmo::INT4);
    END LOOP;
  END $$;
DROP FUNCTION city_set(parent_oktmo INTEGER);
DROP TYPE oktmo_name;

COMMIT;
```

When I try to start up my application I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:changelogs/db-changelog-4.x.xml::GEO-6154_1::kadzhaev:
     Reason: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I think it could happen because of `$$` sign but how I can fix it?

Comment: It could help if you run it again with log level set to debug and then paste the full stacktrace of the exception. (When you run liquibase from command line just add `--logLevel=debug`)

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @NIravModi, hi, as far as I remember I used `splitStatements=false` to solve this issue.

Comment: Okay anyway I had used <createProcedure>

Answer (score 3):

Just add splitStatements="false" and stripComments="false" to the <sql> label.

```
<changeSet id="1" author="admin">
    <sql splitStatements="false" stripComments="false" >
        <![CDATA[
            your SQL
        ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I have resolved using

```
<createProcedure dbms="postgresql"
                 encoding="utf8"
                 path="yourFunction.sql"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
/>
```